# Aligning a div to the center in CSS

Tags: background, html

So my code, in the body section:

```
<div style="width:154px; height:77px;background-image:url('resources/images/logoanim.gif')"></div>
```

The image is stuck on the top left of the page.

How can I align this to the center of the page?

```
background-position:center
```

Did NOT work :?

Help is appreciated!
Sorry for the limited info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a fixed with and height its not that hard.

- Make your div position absolute
- margin-left and margin-right are auto
- top:50%;
- margin-top:-38px (half the height)

Which results in:

```
position:absolute;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
top:50%;
margin-top:-38px;
width:154px;
height:77px;
background-image:url('resources/images/logoanim.gif')
```

Comment: Ok, the image is still on the left, but it's lower now.

Comment: How about instead of top:50%; i do left:%50; ?

Comment: Do you only want the image to be in the center of the div? Then you use the `background-position:center center` style